# How to (image) capture map and copy it to clipboard using QGIS?

Tags: qgis

Essentially, I want to copy a map to clipboard (not `Save as Image`).

Comment: On my todo list :)

Answer (score 4):

You can install the plugin "Copy Canvas To Clipboard" from the official QGIS plugin repository.

The plugin does exactly what you want (Disclaimer: I'm the author of the plugin)

Comment: Extremely handy.  Just one keystroke: perfect.The confirmation

Comment: In QGIS3 this plugin is now called QCopycanvas. From the plugin description: "This tool can be used to copy the map canvas and place it in the clipboard (Using button or shortcut `Ctrl-Space`). This plugin is based on the plugin "Copy Canvas to Clipboard" in QGIS 2 by Bo Victor Thomsen - Municipality of Frederikssund."

Answer (score 2):

On Windows, pressing the `Print screen` key should do what you want.

Not sure if other OS react the same.

You will have to cut out the menu frame around the map using Gimp or other tools.
Eventually, `File -> Save as Image` would bring you the same result with less effort.

Comment: ...and Save as Image will also give you much better resolution too!

Comment: The number of pixels is the same, just screen resolution. Unless you are using the print composer.

Comment: The comparison was between saving a map as an image (which presumes the print composer) and using print screen to copy to the clip board, in which case the number of pixels will not be the same unless the image resolution is set very low in the print composer.

Comment: I was hoping for a more elegant way of doing this. I am quite surprised there is no one-click snapshot button. In the meantime, I am using the `Grab` (app) in OSX -- this is similar to Windows' `Print screen`. Thanks for all the input!

Answer (score 2):

In QGIS 3.4 Madeira (and I believe also 3.2 Bonn), this is a native feature accessible through `Project > Import/Export > Export Map to Image...`

[image: qgis-export-to-img-menu]

This will take you to the following menu window, where you can make further adjustments to the exported image, and in the lower left corner, there is the sought after button `Copy to Clipboard`

[image: qgis-export-to-img]

Comment: would want to know how you did the snapshot for the procedure you just showed because for me the sniping and print screen doesn't work.

Comment: @AmeliaNicodemus I am uncertain what you mean. Do you want to know how I made the screenshots I included in the answer, so the images you can see here on this site? Or is your question QGIS-related, so about the content of the answer?

Comment: Yes, I normally press Ctrl Alt PrtScn, however that was not working so well, the moment you click on project, import export export map to image and attempt taking a print screen then it does not work but by just pressing PrtScn alone works. It also depends on what keyboard you have got.

Comment: @AmeliaNicodemus sorry for the late reply. Actually, when you posted your comment, I look at my answer and wondered about that myself. I especially like the first one, where the correct item is highlighted in the drop-down menu, but no cursor is visible. To he honest, I have no clue how I did it, but I would be interested in knowing that myself. I'll have to investigate and try a few different methods I currently find on my system at home. Hmm, judging from screenshot 2, it should have been the ms windows snipping tool with time delay.

Answer (score 0):

Sure there must be a more "elegant" way.  And it would also be useful for a number of people, I guess.  Plus, it would be neat to define the resolution, something different than a bare screenshot.

To implement, I would have a look in the ksnapshot (https://www.kde.org/applications/graphics/ksnapshot/) source code: there is a convenient button which copies the captured bitmap into the clipboard, ready to be pasted anywhere.

If I can find enough time/energy, I'll try to contribute a bit by addressing this issue (I feel guilty: I use QGIS so much and I don't contribute enough...).